# Using decodable to parse data from two different containers in same json - swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, decodable

I wanted to know if it is possible to parse data from a json file to create a type on where the json file stores multiple objects of the type you want to create in more then one place in the json data structure. What I mean is using the example json below I want to create two "Weather" objects. one from "Currently" container and one from "daily" > "Data" container. I shall post my code below that works for getting "currently" data but I am unsure on how to use same Weather struct to then get data from daily container. I want to end up with one array of Weather type with two objects, one from "currently" and one from "daily" containers.

p.s. I understand one way to solve this is to have two different structs or two different classes of Weather, one for Currently and the other for Forecast. Suppose this may be better in defining what the data is but would be interested to know if what I describe above is possible.

```
{
"currently": {
    "time": 1520250330,
    "summary": "Clear",
    "icon": "clear-night",
    "nearestStormDistance": 198,
    "nearestStormBearing": 16,
    "precipIntensity": 0,
    "precipProbability": 0,
    "temperature": 41.42,
    "apparentTemperature": 41.42,
    "dewPoint": 33.95,
    "humidity": 0.75,
    "pressure": 1027.07,
    "windSpeed": 2.89,
    "windGust": 5.43,
    "windBearing": 39,
    "cloudCover": 0,
    "uvIndex": 0,
    "visibility": 10,
    "ozone": 346.58
},
"daily": {
    "summary": "Light rain on Wednesday, with temperatures falling to 58°F on Sunday.",
    "icon": "rain",
    "data": [
        {
            "time": 1520236800,
            "summary": "Partly cloudy overnight.",
            "icon": "partly-cloudy-night",
            "sunriseTime": 1520260588,
            "sunsetTime": 1520302114,
            "moonPhase": 0.64,
            "precipIntensity": 0.0002,
            "precipIntensityMax": 0.0018,
            "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1520283600,
            "precipProbability": 0.13,
            "precipType": "rain",
            "temperatureHigh": 58.02,
            "temperatureHighTime": 1520298000,
            "temperatureLow": 46.48,
            "temperatureLowTime": 1520348400,
            "apparentTemperatureHigh": 58.02,
            "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1520298000,
            "apparentTemperatureLow": 42.09,
            "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1520348400,
            "dewPoint": 36.4,
            "humidity": 0.62,
            "pressure": 1024.6,
            "windSpeed": 4.65,
            "windGust": 15.36,
            "windGustTime": 1520269200,
            "windBearing": 35,
            "cloudCover": 0.08,
            "uvIndex": 5,
            "uvIndexTime": 1520280000,
            "visibility": 10,
            "ozone": 340.2,
            "temperatureMin": 41.36,
            "temperatureMinTime": 1520254800,
            "temperatureMax": 58.02,
            "temperatureMaxTime": 1520298000,
            "apparentTemperatureMin": 37.53,
            "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1520262000,
            "apparentTemperatureMax": 58.02,
            "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1520298000
        }
```

Current struct:

```
struct Weather: Decodable {
let temperature: Double
var temperatureCelsius: Double {
    let temp = 5 / 9 * (temperature - 32) as Double
    return Double(round(temp))
}
let humidity: Double
let rainProbability: Int
let summary: String
let icon: String
let temperatureMax: Double?
let temperatureMin: Double?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case temperature
    case humidity
    case rainProbability = "precipProbability"
    case summary
    case icon
    case temperatureMax
    case temperatureMin
}

private enum CurrentlyKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case currently
}

public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CurrentlyKeys.self)
    let weatherValues = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .currently)
    temperature = try weatherValues.decode(Double.self, forKey: .temperature)
    humidity = try weatherValues.decode(Double.self, forKey: .humidity)
    rainProbability = try weatherValues.decode(Int.self, forKey: .rainProbability)
    summary = try weatherValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .summary)
    icon = try weatherValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .icon)
    temperatureMax = try weatherValues.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .temperatureMax)
    temperatureMin = try weatherValues.decodeIfPresent(Double.self, forKey: .temperatureMin)
}
```

Parsing data:

```
do {
      let currentWeather = try JSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: data)
      print(currentWeather.summary)
    } catch let error {
      print("error: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: If you want to reuse the weather data dictionary you have to create a separate struct instead of parse the `nestedContainer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving the issue while still having the benefits of just using Codable is to create a type corresponding to the response you are getting, which has the properties you need (a Weather object for currentWeather and an an array of Weather objects for the forecast).

In this specific case it is a bit more complicated because the forecast array is wrapped in yet another JSON object. You could solve this by providing a custom decoding implementation instead of using the one generated by Codable:

```
struct WeatherApiResponse: Decodable {

    fileprivate struct DailyContainer: Decodable {
        let data: [Weather]
    }

    let currentWeather: Weather
    let dailyWeather: [Weather]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let keyedContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        currentWeather = try keyedContainer.decode(Weather.self, forKey: .currentWeather)
        dailyWeather = (try keyedContainer.decode(DailyContainer.self, forKey: .dailyWeather)).data
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currentWeather = "current"
        case dailyWeather = "daily"
    }
}
```

And decode the two properties you need as follows:

```
if let response = try? jsonDecoder.decode(WeatherApiResponse.self, from: data) {
    print(response.currentWeather)
    print(response.dailyWeather)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Have just tried this approach and it works well. Found the ` (try keyedContainer.decode(DailyContainer.self, forKey: .dailyWeather)).data ` very interesting. One to remember!